# I am trying to transfer Last Name, First Name and a date to another tab(s) on my spreadsheet based on when a certain cell is filled in

Tags: function, google-sheets

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nvsZi12vrw2ZvWzI65FppWwMShK9mw5zT35kw1hF7mU/edit?usp=sharing

I am trying to get the data from the overall tab to automatically fill in on the other tabs based on when a date is filled in.

For example, when I fill in the date for "Natalie Grenfell" under 4-LD tab, I want the Last Name, First Name and Date to automatically transfer to the "LD" tab on the spreadsheet so I'm not constantly copying and pasting the same info.

Same goes for the others. If I were to fill out a date for "Natalie Grenfell" under the 8-ASD Tab I'd want the Name and date to automatically transfer to the "ASD" tab

Is this possible??

The link at the top is a copy of my original.

I've tried multiple functions but can't figure out right one or if this is even possible to do

Comment: Just something to ponder over coz of the way the sheet is going to be used/structured. The data (Name + date) you are going to pull via formulas into sub-sheets (LD, ASD, SS) from *Overall* tab is going to be **dynamic** in nature ie., any row deletions/additions at some point of time to existing data in *Overall* tab will automatically adjust the data in sub-sheets *but* the attendance you are going to mark (in Column_D) will remain **static** & will ultimately result in a total mismatched alignment of name→attendance thing you are creating.

Comment: Is there a way the attendance can stay with the name?

Comment: You could go with `[google-apps-script]` to copy-paste *OR* move the data from *Overall* to sub-sheets so as for it to stay independent once transferred over & be fool-proof

Comment: Do you have a formula for that? Sorry I'm a school teacher and I know basic formulas for sheets but don't know how to build complex ones for this. If you have a forumla you could share with me that I could copy and paste into my document or send me a document with what you are talking about I'd get it better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I understood the problem but can you try this filter formula in LD!A2 :

```
=filter('Overall Tracking Sheet'!A2:C,'Overall Tracking Sheet'!C2:C<>"")
```

For ASD and SS tabs, I would need more details to help you (example of expected output would help a lot).

Comment: For ASD, this formula is working on my copy of the file but I think there is a better way to do it : `=let(dataToFilter,{tocol({'Overall Tracking Sheet'!A2:A,'Overall Tracking Sheet'!A2:A,'Overall Tracking Sheet'!A2:A}),tocol({'Overall Tracking Sheet'!B2:B,'Overall Tracking Sheet'!B2:B,'Overall Tracking Sheet'!B2:B}),TOCOL('Overall Tracking Sheet'!E2:G)},filter(dataToFilter,query(dataToFilter,"Select Col3")<>""))`. For SS, could be something similar.

Comment: for SS, ```=let(dataToFilter,{tocol({'Overall Tracking Sheet'!A2:A,'Overall Tracking Sheet'!A2:A,'Overall Tracking Sheet'!A2:A}),tocol({'Overall Tracking Sheet'!B2:B,'Overall Tracking Sheet'!B2:B,'Overall Tracking Sheet'!B2:B}),TOCOL('Overall Tracking Sheet'!H2:J)},filter(dataToFilter,query(dataToFilter,"Select Col3")<>""))```

Comment: This helped a lot and worked!I am needing an updated formula for the LD tabs. Because the 6-?? I didn't know what the consequence was until now. This would also be a LD tab. Are you able to get me an updated forumal for the LD one? I updated the example one if that helps?

Comment: here the updated formula for LD tab : `=let(dataToFilter,{tocol({'Overall Tracking Sheet'!A2:A,'Overall Tracking Sheet'!A2:A}),tocol({'Overall Tracking Sheet'!B2:B,'Overall Tracking Sheet'!B2:B}),TOCOL('Overall Tracking Sheet'!C2:D)},filter(dataToFilter,query(dataToFilter,"Select Col3")<>""))`.

Comment: Hey Antoine, I am now having issues with being able to keep attendance on my other tabs. Is there a way the names can be entered and I can keep attendance column where the attendance will stay with the kid.

Comment: Hey, unfortunately your output tabs are a blend of dynamic and static values so the best (robust) solution is to check attendance on the same input tab and to have another tab to analyse all the static data (where you can filter each type of meeting for example)

Answer (score 0):

My formula is a bit long but works on all the sheets.

> =QUERY(ArrayFormula(SPLIT(TOCOL( FILTER('Overall Tracking Sheet'!A2:A&"*"&'Overall Tracking Sheet'!B2:B&"*"&'Overall Tracking Sheet'!C2:J,REGEXMATCH('Overall Tracking Sheet'!C1:J1,**"ASD"**))),"_")),"select * where Col3 > 0")

- You only need to replace the "**ASD**" with other conditions, such as LD and SS. Any matching column header that has the word ASD, DD or SS will be in the sheet.

[image: a]

**ASD Sheet**
[image]